# Concatenate href with a span tag

Tags: xml, xpath, odoo, odoo-10, qweb

I would like to know how I can concatenate a href tag with a span because the link to generate is the result of join these two tags

```
<a href='first part of link&amp;mount=&amp;'> 
<span t-field="Second part of link" t-field-options="{'widget':'False'}"/>Clic here
</a>
```

Comment: why? ask properly by providing the needed info

Comment: Hello @Axel Mendoza,  I am modifying an odoo report 10
I have an online payment service that consists of a fixed url **[href] **+ a number (which is the amount paid online by the client) **[span]**, the union of these two elements results in the url that the client must click to pay.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use an span for that to build an attribute value. You could get it done using QWeb attribute format to generate outputs like:

```
<a t-attf-href="{{base_url}}?mount={{amount_value}}">Clic here</a>
```

You could read about it at:

https://www.odoo.com/documentation/11.0/reference/qweb.html#attributes

Comment: Thank you @Axel Mendoza, it is posible to put **&amp;doc.amount_total" t-field-options="{'widget':'False'}** in {{amount_vaue}} ? I have tried to do it that way but it does not work

Comment: You could put just `{{doc.amount_total}}`, no need to put `options` and `t-field`